# Autocomplete on wrong form field

Tags: javascript, php, autocomplete

I know some php/html/css but javascript is where I need help. I found on web autocomplete script, but this doesn't work on more than two input fields.

There are two problems I need to solve.

1. When you type in first box, autocomplete shows in second one. How to make script show autocomplete on box where user is typing?
2. I need to use the same autocomplete on multiple fields on my site.

The javascript syntax I use is:

```
var MIN_LENGTH = 2;

$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#keyword").keyup(function() {
    var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
    if (keyword.length >= MIN_LENGTH) {

        $.get( "http://example.com/autofill/auto-complete.php", { keyword: keyword } )
        .done(function( data ) {
            $('#results').html('');
            var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $(results).each(function(key, value) {
                $('#results').append('<div class="item">' + value + '</div>');
            })

            $('.item').click(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $('#keyword').val(text);
            })

        });
    } else {
        $('#results').html('');
    }
});

$("#keyword").blur(function(){
        $("#results").fadeOut(500);
    })
    .focus(function() {     
        $("#results").show();
    });

});
```

Comment: You mean JavaScript, not Java...

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to re-use the same autocomplete code you need to give the scope of the function the context of the correct DOM element.

Here's a a quick jsfiddle with some simple HTML code, but it should give a basic example of how to bind the same events to multiple dom structures.

[DEMO: JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/580s5yf9/1/)

JS

```
var MIN_LENGTH = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".keyword").keyup(function() {

    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    var $results = $parent.find('.results');
    var keyword = $(this).val();

    if (keyword.length >= MIN_LENGTH) {

      $.get("/echo/json/", {
          keyword: keyword
        })
        .done(function(data) {

          $results.html('');
          data = ['test', 'test2'];
          //data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          $(data).each(function(key, value) {
            $results.append('<div class="item">' + value + '</div>');
          });

        });
    } else {
      $results.html('');
    }
  });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="autcomplete">
  <input class="keyword" /> 
  <ul class="results"></ul>
</div>

<div class="autcomplete">
  <input class="keyword" /> 
  <ul class="results"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is probably right but I dont know how to properly connect this with my php stuff.